# Empathy with Gnome Online Accounts (GOA)

Tags: empathy

How is Empathy supposed to work in Ubuntu 12.10 with Gnome 3.6?

I added my Google and Facebook accounts to GOA and enabled "Chat" for both, but Empathy does not use the accounts. Instead it says "You need to setup an account to see contacts here. " and opens the Ubuntu Online Accounts.

How can I fix this? Is there a bug report for this?

*I at least found bug reports and a blog post that I linked to in my answer below. I still would like to know why Empathy, as a Gnome application, does not work with GOA even when I compile and run a version from gnome.org.*

Answer (score 4):

Tested on Ubuntu 13.04 and later (but the package is available also for 12.10 so it should work).

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mcp-account-manager-goa
sudo apt-get remove --purge mcp-account-manager-uoa
sudo reboot
```

After the reboot empathy will use the Gnome Online Accounts instead of the Ubuntu one.

Answer (score 2):

I found bug reports and a blog post related to this:

- [Launchpad #1067901 - can't configure any accounts in empathy](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bug/1067901)
- [Launchpad #1060060 - Unable to modify empathy accounts in gnome-online-accounts](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bug/1060060)
- [Ubuntu Online Accounts and the Ubuntu GNOME Remix](http://jeremy.bicha.net/2012/10/06/ubuntu-online-accounts-and-gnome/)
- [Ubuntu 12.10 Known Issues](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/ReleaseNotes/12.10#Known_issues)

Compiling Empathy 3.6.2 myself did not help unfortunately.

I do not understand why an application of the GNOME project does not work with the Gnome Online Accounts, but with the Ubuntu Online Accounts.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for Empathy in the Ubuntu Software Center that would solve this issue: GNOME multi-protocol chat and call client (GOA plugin). After a reboot Empathy used the gnome online accounts!

Comment: But I'm using Ubuntu 13.04...

Comment: Do you know whether this is in 12.10 or not, which is what the OP is using?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't, @ThomasWard.